# Arabic Character's Are not Showing properly in RTL Input Field(RTL pro is A Package that help's to Write Arabic and English)

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, user-interface, arabic

I Am Using the [RTL pro Package](https://github.com/pnarimani/RTLTMPro) in Unity To Write the Arabic and English Language. The RTL Pro Package is Working perfectly fine and I can Write the Arabic and English. But there is Some Issue.

When I Try to Write the English Letter First and then Arabic in same Sentence, Like Example: "Hello, غتناب Buddy". This is The Correct Format I required. but in the RTL Pro Package it is not Showing properly. It Appears Like this "Hello ل ايا ي Buddy ".
Image: [image]

My desired result is that: "Hello, غتناب Buddy".
Any help Regarding this Issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You asked this yesterday [The Arabic is Not Writing properly in unity(Using the RTL Pro Package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76817464/the-arabic-is-not-writing-properly-in-unityusing-the-rtl-pro-package)

Comment: Yes, but I edit the Whole Question and posted it Again with the proper Details.

Comment: I still feel that the poster yesterday who said ask the author hit it on the head.  The author is the expert

Comment: I tried but the Author is Not Responding, So I feel to post it here.